# Fabric rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)

Tags: python, django, windows, rsync, fabric

I'm trying to deploy a Python/Django/Mezzanine website to DO using FABRIC.

My dev environment is Windows 10 with Ubuntu WSL

I've checked the server and /mezzanine/my_cms exists

When I run `fab create` I get the error

```
dup() in/out/err failed
rsync: read error: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at 
/usr/src/rsync/rsync-3.0.8/io.c(760) [sender=3.0.8]

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 12) while executing 
'rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude "*.pyo" --exclude "*.db" --exclude 
".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage" --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude 
"/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22  ' 
/c/WebDev/site_env/my_cms/ 
saleh_cms@123.456.789.012:/home/saleh_cms/mezzanine/my_cms'

Aborting.
Disconnecting from 123.456.789.012... done.
```

If I try running rsync manually

```
rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude "*.pyo" --exclude "*.db" --exclude 
".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage" --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude 
"/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22  ' 
/c/WebDev/site_env/my_cms/ 
saleh_cms@123.456.789.012:/home/saleh_cms/mezzanine/my_cms'
```

I get the following error

The source and destination cannot both be remote.
   rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /usr/src/rsync/rsync- 
   3.0.8/main.c(1148) [Receiver=3.0.8]

I hardcoded the path /c/WebDev/site_env/my_cms/ to avoid using the colon which rsync interprets as a remote host

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Before running the `rsync` command, CD in `/c/WebDev/site_env/my_cms/`. Then run:

```
rsync  --exclude "*.pyc" --exclude "*.pyo" --exclude "*.db" --exclude 
".DS_Store" --exclude ".coverage" --exclude "local_settings.py" --exclude 
"/static" --exclude "/.git" --exclude "/.hg" -pthrvz  --rsh='ssh  -p 22  ' 
. saleh_cms@123.456.789.012:/home/saleh_cms/mezzanine/my_cms'
```

(same command, but replace your local dir by a point)